How can I efficiently distort and undistort image points?
I would like to find a fast implementation of distortion and undistortion of image points. Below are my current implementations which work well
# Given a set of distorted image points, I can use cv2.undistortpoints
def undistort_points(points, kmat, distcoeff):
    undistorted_pts_normed = cv2.undistortPoints(points, kmat, distcoeff).squeeze()
    cx = kmat[0,2]
    cy = kmat[1,2]
    fx = kmat[0,0]
    fy = kmat[1,1]
    undistorted_uv = np.empty(undistorted_pts_normed.shape)
    undistorted_uv[:,0] = fx * undistorted_pts_normed[:,0] + cx
    undistorted_uv[:,1] = fy * undistorted_pts_normed[:,1] + cy
    ret = [Point(x=int(pt[0]),y=int(pt[1])) for pt in undistorted_uv]

# To distort the points I use the distortion equations
def distort_points(points, kmat, distcoeff):
    cx = kmat[0,2]
    cy = kmat[1,2]
    fx = kmat[0,0]
    fy = kmat[1,1]
    k1,k2,p1,p2,k3 = distcoeff

    # Convert to normalized points
    normed_points = np.empty(points.shape)
    normed_points[:,0] = (points[:,0] - cx)/fx
    normed_points[:,1] = (points[:,1] - cy)/fy

    # Apply distortion
    r2 = normed_points[:,0]**2 + normed_points[:,1]**2 # r squared
    radial_dist = (1 + k1*r2 + k2*(r2**2) + k3*(r2**3))[...,np.newaxis]
    tangential_dist = np.empty(normed_points.shape)
    tangential_dist[:,0] = p2 * (r2 + 2 * (normed_points[:,0]**2)) + 2 * p1 * normed_points[:,0] * normed_points[:,1]
    tangential_dist[:,1] = p1 * (r2 + 2 * (normed_points[:,1]**2)) + 2 * p2 * normed_points[:,0] * normed_points[:,1]
    distorted_points = radial_dist * normed_points + tangential_dist

    # Return points in uv space
    distorted_uv = np.empty(distorted_points.shape)
    distorted_uv[:,0] = fx * distorted_points[:,0] + cx
    distorted_uv[:,1] = fy * distorted_points[:,1] + cy
    return distorted_uv

I've come across cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap which I can run once to store a mapping for each pixel to undistort, hence making the undistortion very efficient. However, I'm not sure how to use the mapx and mapy for image points instead of full images. Below shows how I compute the mapx and mapy mappings.
    newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(kmat, distcoeff, (1920, 1080), 0, (1920, 1080))
    mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(kmat, distcoeff, None, newcameramtx, (1920, 1080), 5)

I would also like to know if it's possible to use the same mappings to convert from undistorted points to distorted points. Any help would be much appreciated!

if you want the new position of point x1, y1, read the values dx = mapx[x1, y1] and dy = mapy[x,y] and, there I'm not sure, either your new position is then [dx, dy] or it is [x1+dx, y1+dy]. You can probably easily try that yourelf in a simple experiment. Also make sure that reading the values from a 2D array is correct, maybe x and y ordering are switched. I dont know numpy.

Image points, or entire images?
The lens distortion equation is a closed form in one direction, but requires numerical inversion (a few iterations) in the other direction. OpenCV already has functions for both directions, which operate on individual points:

cv::projectPoints() applies distortion (also projection but you can set that to identity)
cv::undistortImagePoints(), cv::undistortPoints()

Warping each individual pixel coordinate of an entire image does not count as "just some points".
Warping an entire image is another matter and uses other functions. In the other direction, direct calculation is reasonably cheap, but generating the LUT makes the operation even cheaper. In the one direction, direct calculation is not cheap, so it pays to generate the LUT.

cv::initInverseRectificationMap()
cv::undistort() or cv::initUndistortRectifyMap()

Arbitrary LUTs can be inverted numerically, yielding reasonable results in most cases. If (!) that becomes necessary, you can do that, and that will incur a one-time cost of a few iterations of cv::remap() on the LUT to be inverted.

Thanks for your response! I wasn't aware that projectPoints() could apply distortion. I was mainly wondering if I could pre-compute a LUT for image point distortion/undistortion and how to do that with cv2 or numpy.
